# Use while to select a set of tables using id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012 and want to translate this into T-SQL code:

1. Get a set of IDs from some table. i.e.: `select id from id_table where id > 3`.
2. Use these IDs as input to another query, for example:

```sql
SELECT count(*) nb , [status]
FROM [tbl_dest] as dest with (nolock) 
inner join  [tbl_messages] as source with (nolock)
on dest.message_id=source.id
where source.id=338
```

I want to use the second query using the IDs that I got from the first query in the last where clause is `where source.id=338` using a loop or a variable etc.

Can you please help with your knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One straightforward option here would be to use a `WHERE IN` clause:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) nb,
    [status]
FROM [tbl_dest] AS dest WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [tbl_messages] AS source WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON dest.message_id = source.id
WHERE source.id IN (SELECT id FROM id_table WHERE id > 3);
```

We can also rephrase the `WHERE IN` using another join:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) nb,
    [status]
FROM [tbl_dest] AS dest WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [tbl_messages] AS source WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON dest.message_id = source.id
INNER JOIN id_table it
    ON source.id = it.id
WHERE it.id > 3;
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but I want to have seperate select statement. For example: While (Variable in select id from id_table where id >3)
Select SELECT
    COUNT(*) nb,
    [status]
FROM [tbl_dest] AS dest WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [tbl_messages] AS source WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON dest.message_id = source.id
WHERE source.id= Variable 
END

Comment: @GitZine Then use the first option with `WHERE IN`.  There could be a performance benefit to using a join however.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, your solution work and is more optimized : )

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor` is not required. Just try to use subquery;

```
    SELECT count(*) nb , [status] FROM [tbl_dest] as dest with (nolock) inner join 
    [tbl_messages] as source with (nolock) on 
    dest.message_id=source.id where source.id IN (select id from id_table where id >3)
```